# How to convert from AX data (container) to C# collection

Tags: c#, collections, containers, axapta

It is possible to convert data from axapta container to a C# collection like ArrayList, or maybe serialize and deserialize from one to another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct conversion, but you can address each member of the container:

```
using Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet;
AxaptaContainer axContainer = (AxaptaContainer)objDAXCn.Call("someClass","someStaticMethod",Var1,Var2,var3);    
for (int i = 1; i <= axContainer.Count; i++)
{ 
    someStr = axContainer.get_Item(i).toString();
}
```

Reference:
http://dynamics-ax.blogspot.com/2007/06/net-bc-custom-app-part-iii-container.html