# Return a list to .NET Business Connector

Tags: c#, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++, business-connector

Currently, I am using the following code:

```
        Axapta ax = new Axapta();
        string tableName;
        ArrayList ax_cont = null;
        ax.Logon(null, null, null, null);
        try
        {
            ax_cont = (ArrayList)ax.CallStaticClassMethod("Code_Generator", "tableNames");
            for (int i = 1; i <= ax_cont.Count; i++)
            {
                tableName = ax_cont[i].ToString();
                tablesCB.Items.Add(tableName);
            }    
        }
        catch { }
```

But I'm getting a type conversion exception.

What do I need to do in C# when a list is returned from ax dynamics as an `AxpataObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what `Code_generator::tableNames()` returns.

It certainly does not return an `ArrayList` but most likely an AX `List`, and the two are not the same and cannot be casted.

One way would be to let AX return a container, [then access that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393378/convert-from-axapta-data-container-to-c-sharp-collection).

Otherwise you could access the AX `List` directly using [AxaptaObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.dynamics.businessconnectornet.axaptaobject.aspx)

```
AxpataObject ax_cont = ax.CallStaticClassMethod("Code_Generator", "tableNames");
AxpataObject ax_it = ax_cont.Call("getEnumerator");
while (ax_it.Call("moveNext"))
     // Hope you get it
```

Comment: I'll use the container. I do not want to make too many interop calls.